# why in Scala a function type needs to be passed in separate group of arguments into a function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to scala , I have written same code in 2 ways . But i am bit confused between 2 ways. In Second way argument type of f are derived automatically but in type1 scala compiler is not able to do the same . I just want to understand what is the thought behind this .

Type1: Gives compilation error

```
def rightFold[A,B](xs:List[A],z:B,f:(A,B) => B ): B = xs match {

    case Nil => z
    case Cons(x,xs) => f(x,rightFold(xs,z,f))
  }

  def sum1(l:List[Int]) =  rightFold(l,0.0,_ + _)
```

Type2 : Works fine

```
  def rightFold[A,B](xs:List[A],z:B)(f:(A,B) => B ): B = xs match {

    case Nil => z
    case Cons(x,xs) => f(x,rightFold(xs,z)(f))
  }

  def sum1(l:List[Int]) =  rightFold(l,0.0)(_ + _)
```

Comment: A rough guideline to remember in Scala: The type inference isn't perfect, and it tends to work better when you curry.

Answer (score 4):

Type inference flows from left-to-right *through argument lists*. In other words, type information from left argument *lists* is available in right argument *lists*, but argument types within *the same list* are inferred *independently*.

Comment: @Mittag Makes sense .

Comment: Well, apparently not, otherwise you (and the countless others that have been bitten by this) wouldn't have asked this question ;-) But, that's the way it is. Scala's Type Inference *is* limited compared to, say Haskell. For one, Scala has subtyping, which *massively* complicates type inference. Plus, the Scala maintainers are very sensitive about anything that would compromise good, *helpful* compile errors.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about function types need to be passed in a separate group of arguments (currying).The problem is with your usage of `+` on types that the Scala doesn't know about yet.

When you curry a function, the compiler is able to infer the type of the first two arguments as being `List[Int]` and `Double` already. This allows the `+` to be resolved as it knows that the types are `Int` and `Dobule` on the two sides.

Now why can't the compiler do the same with the single arguments list - that's just how it is, type information is not available within an argument list.

Answer (score 3):

Type 1 would work if instead of passing in `_ + _` you pass in `(a: Int, b: Double) => (a + b))`. Currying the function lets you use the underline syntax, because the scala compiler has inferred what types A and B are by the time you try and pass in the addition function.

Comment: The distinction isn't between using `_` or not, but about giving explicit types or not: `(_: Int) + (_: Double)` works in first case, `(a, b) => a + b` works in the second.

Answer (score 0):

With single list an inferred type of `A` depends on the types of `xs` and `f`. But with the two lists of arguments it depends just on the `xs` type.